# execute the code after some time depending upon the Characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

array = ["Rashid", "Kalam", "NEO"]

Rashid has six characters so it consoles after 6 seconds.

kalam has 5 so it should console after word 5 second
and as so on

Answer (score 2):

Should the timer start for all together or one after one?

I have it here one after one

```js
let sleep = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));

(async () => {
let array = ["Rashid", "Kalam", "NEO"]

console.log("Start counter now");
for(let item of array) {
   let { length } = item;
   await sleep(1000 * length);
   console.log(item);
}

})()
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is your friend.

```
let array = ["Rashid", "Kalam", "NEO"];
array.map((name) => setTimeout(()=>console.log(name), name.length * 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['rashid', 'Kalam', 'neo'].forEach(name => setTimeout(() => console.log(name), name.length * 1000))
```

Comment: Feel free to explain your reasoning so that the person who posted can learn as well.

Comment: It's not clear if the timeout/code should execute after the first one in order of the array, or if it's completely async and fires in parallel... if that's not the case, the above comment is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set interval function and then add the value in the array also 1000ms means 1 second

```
setInterval(function(){ array = ["Rashid"] }, 6000); 
// use second set interval and add another name or remove. 
setInterval(function(){ array = ["Kalam"] }, 5000);

the 6000 means 6 seconds and 5000 means 5 seconds.
```